# textView.getLineCount() returns 0 after setTextSize method

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm trying to resize my textview to fit in 1 line.

```
while (titleText.getLineCount() > 1) {
    float scaledDensity = ManagerStorage.mainActivity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
    titleText.setTextSize(titleText.getTextSize() / scaledDensity - 0.5f);
    Log.i("lines", "" + titleText.getLineCount());
    }
```

However, while loop executes only once. After setTextSize method, getLineCount will always return 0. While loop is executed with runOnUiThread on runnable that works after view is returned by onCreateView method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
while (titleText.getLineCount() > 1) {
        float scaledDensity = ManagerStorage.mainActivity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
        titleText.setTextSize(titleText.getTextSize() / scaledDensity - 0.5f);

        titleText.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int lineCount = titleText.getLineCount();
                Log.i("lines", "" + titleText.getLineCount());
                // Use lineCount here
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: But I don't need to get it once, I need to get it updated after every setTextSize in my while loop, however then it starts always returning 0.

Comment: check the answer now